# redmine モジュール(wiki)追加

Tags: redmine

redmineを使ってタスク管理しています。
1つのプロジェクトに2つのtextile入力できるモジュールが欲しいと考えています。
wikiが複数のタブで存在するイメージで、一方はガイドライン的内容
、もう一方は情報共有のwikiとして分けて利用したいです。
このようなことは素のredmineできるのでしょうか？
もしくはtextile編集できるモジュールを追加するプラグインで、メジャーなものが、あれば教えていただきたいです。

よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 1):

Wikiではありませんが [alexbevi/redmine_knowledgebase: A knowledgebase plugin for Redmine](https://github.com/alexbevi/redmine_knowledgebase) を導入して 使い分ける方法を思いつきました。

knowledgebase は、記事をカテゴリ分けして管理する構造で、Wikiとは趣が異なりますが、情報共有には向いていると思います。

Textile記法も使えます。

Comment: wikiでも使えますが、knowledgebase はgraphvizも使えます。おそらくPlantUMLも。